# Why does my program run on Xcode but not on codeblocks

Tags: c, xcode, codeblocks

beginner programmer here. I am making a card war game using Xcode. However, my prof uses code::blocks to grade. When I run my code in Xcode it runs perfectly, but when I run in code::blocks it has spits an error:
Process returned -1 (0xFFFFFFF). Can anyone tell me what's happening and why it's not running from one IDE to the next? It's important that I make it run on codeblocks since that's what I will be graded on.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#define DECK_SIZE 52

unsigned int rounds_played = 0 ;
unsigned int wars_played = 0 ;

/*
Base data structure: deck. It's a stack that can hold up to
deck_size cards.

A card is represented as a nunmber from 2 to 14. 14 is an Ace.

*/
typedef struct {
  // basically a stack
  char* slots ;
  unsigned int slot_pointer ;
  unsigned int deck_size ;
} Deck ;

/* Operations on deck:

make_deck: creates and initialize a deck that can hold up to *size*
cards.

enqueue(deck, item): puts a card on top of the stack
dequeue(deck): draws a card from the stack
dump_deck(d): views content of deck d. free slots will have value
              of zero (0)
deck_empty(d): inspects a deck to see whether a deck holds any card

*/
Deck* make_deck(unsigned int size) ;
void enqueue(Deck* deck, char item);
char dequeue(Deck* deck) ;
void dump_deck(Deck *d);
int deck_empty(Deck *d) ;

/* make_initial_deck: sets up a 52-card deck, shuffled */
Deck *make_initial_deck() ;

/* deal: cards from deck *sorce get split evenly between decks
         *d1 and *d2 
*/
void deal(Deck *source, Deck *deck1, Deck *deck2);


void play(Deck* d1, Deck* d2, Deck* tmp);
bool game_won(Deck* d1, Deck* d2) ;
unsigned int deck_cards_number(Deck* d) ;
char* print_card(char card) ;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  srand(time(NULL));

  Deck* initial_deck = make_initial_deck() ;
  Deck* d1 = make_deck(DECK_SIZE) ;
  Deck* d2 = make_deck(DECK_SIZE) ;

  printf("Dumping initial deck:\n");
  dump_deck(initial_deck) ;

  deal(initial_deck, d1, d2) ;

  printf("Dumping d1:\n");
  dump_deck(d1);

  printf("Dumping d2:\n");
  dump_deck(d2) ;

  Deck* tmp = make_deck(DECK_SIZE) ;
  play(d1, d2, tmp) ;

  return 0 ;
}

/*
 * play: implements the game

*/
void play (Deck* d1, Deck* d2, Deck *tmp) {
  rounds_played++ ;
  char card1, card2 ;
  /* printf("Player 1 deck:\n"); dump_deck(d1) ; */
  /* printf("Player 2 deck:\n"); dump_deck(d2) ; */
  /* printf("tmp deck:\n"); dump_deck(tmp) ; */

  if (d1->slot_pointer == 0) {
    printf("Player 2 wins the game!\n") ;
    printf("Rounds played: %d\n", rounds_played);
    printf("Wars declared: %d\n", wars_played) ;

    return ;
  } else {
    card1 = dequeue(d1);
    printf("[Player 1]: %s\n", print_card(card1));
  }

  if (d2->slot_pointer == 0) {
    printf("Player 1 wins the game!\n") ;
    printf("Rounds played: %d\n", rounds_played);
    printf("Wars declared: %d\n", wars_played) ;
    return ;
  } else {
    card2 = dequeue(d2);
    printf("[Player 2]: %s\n", print_card(card2));
  }


  // recursive case:
  if (card1 == card2) {
    printf("This is War!\n") ;
    wars_played++ ;

    if ( deck_empty(d1) == 0) {
      enqueue(tmp, dequeue(d1)); // face down card
    }
    if (deck_empty(d2) == 0) {
      enqueue(tmp, dequeue(d2)); // face down card
    }
    /* enqueue(tmp, dequeue(d1)); // face down card */
    /* enqueue(tmp, dequeue(d2)); // face down card */

    enqueue(tmp, card1);
    enqueue(tmp, card2);
  } else {
    if (card1 > card2) {
      // printf("Player1 wins the round!\n") ;
      enqueue(tmp, card1) ;
      enqueue(tmp, card2) ;
      printf("Player 1 wins (%d) cards.\n",
         tmp->slot_pointer) ;
      // dump_deck(tmp);
      while (tmp->slot_pointer > 0) {
    enqueue(d1, dequeue(tmp)) ;
      }
    }
    else {
      // printf("Player2 wins the round!\n") ;
      enqueue(tmp, card1) ;
      enqueue(tmp, card2) ;
      printf("Player 2 wins (%d) cards.\n",
         tmp->slot_pointer) ;
      // dump_deck(tmp);
      while (tmp->slot_pointer > 0) {
    enqueue(d2, dequeue(tmp)) ;
      }
    }
  }
  play(d1,d2,tmp);

  return ;
}

/* Given a souce Deck and two destination Decks d1 and d2, it deals cards from
 * source deck to d1 and d2 so that both decks get half of the cards originally
 * in the source deck.
*/
void deal(Deck *source, Deck *deck1, Deck *deck2) {
  char card ; 
  for(int i=0 ; i< (source->deck_size) ; i++) {
    card = dequeue(source) ;
    if ((i%2) == 0){
      enqueue(deck1, card) ;
    } else {
      enqueue(deck2, card) ;
    }
  }
  return ;
}

// INPUT: two decks, one for each player.
// OUTPUT: true or false, depending on whether one of the two decks
//         holds 52 cards
bool game_won(Deck* d1, Deck* d2){
  if ( (d1->slot_pointer == 51) || (d2->slot_pointer == 51) )
    return true ;
  else
    return false ;
}


// INPUT: the desidered deck size
// OUTPUT: an instance of the Deck data structure, properly intialized
Deck* make_deck(unsigned int size){
  Deck *d = malloc(sizeof(Deck));
  d->slots = malloc(size*sizeof(char)) ;
  memset(d->slots, 0, d->deck_size);
  d->slot_pointer = 0 ;
  d->deck_size = size ;

  return d ;
}

// INPUT: an instance of the Deck data structure
// POST: the contents of the deck will be displayed on standard output.
//       available but empty slots will be represented with zeroes.
void dump_deck(Deck* d) {
  for(unsigned int i=1 ; i<=(d->deck_size) ; i++) {
    printf("%2d  ", d->slots[i-1]) ;
    if( i>0 && i % 13 == 0) {
      printf("\n") ;
    }
  }
  printf("\n");
  return ;
}

// INPUT: An instance of the Deck data structure and a number (in a char)
//  representing a card.
// POST: the card will be added to the deck.
void enqueue(Deck* deck, char item) {
  deck->slots[deck->slot_pointer++] = item ;
  return ;
}


// INPUT: an instance of the Deck data structure
// OUTPUT: a number representing a card from the deck.
char dequeue(Deck* deck) {
  deck->slot_pointer-- ;
  char card = deck->slots[deck->slot_pointer] ;
  deck->slots[deck->slot_pointer] = 0 ;
  return card ;
}

// INPUT: an instance of the Deck data structure
// OUTPUT: 1 if the deck is empty, 0 otherwise.
int deck_empty(Deck *d) {
  if (d->slot_pointer == 0) {
    return 1 ;
  } else {
    return 0 ;
  }
}

// OUTPUT: returns a pointer to a newly-created instance of the Deck data
//         structure, holding DECK_SIZE cards, and randomly shuffled.
Deck *make_initial_deck() {
  Deck *d = make_deck(DECK_SIZE);

  for(int i=0 ; i<4 ; i++) {
    for (int j=2 ; j<15 ; j++) {
      enqueue(d, j) ;
    }
  }


  int n = DECK_SIZE;
  for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++){
    /// get  random element in the listplayer1Hand[26] = 2;
    int j = i + rand() / (RAND_MAX / (n - i) + 1);

    ///swap these two elements
    char temp = d->slots[j];
    d->slots[j] = d->slots[i];
    d->slots[i] = temp;
  }

  return d;
}

// INPUT: a char holding the numeric representation of the card
// OUTPUT: a pointer to a string holding the representation of the card.
//         The representation can be "Ace", "Jack", "Queen" and "King",
//         and the respective number for other cards.
char* print_card(char card) {
  switch (card) {
  case 14 :
    return "Ace" ;
  case 11 :
    return "Jack" ;
  case 12:
    return "Queen" ;
  case 13:
    return "King" ;
  }

  char* str = malloc(4) ;
  sprintf(str, "%2d", card) ;
  return str ; 
}
```

Comment: This is a *long* code. In order to know what is happening one has to debug it. One thing that I can see right away is that you `print_card` is leaking memory. And for nothing, as far as I can tell.

Comment: One thing I notice is in `print_card` you use `malloc` but no corresponding `free`. Might it be better if the function does what it says (prints it) in which case you don't even need an array to build the card name. You would also have to pass the player number for the function to print the description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an obvious bug in this bit of code

```
Deck* make_deck(unsigned int size){
  Deck *d = malloc(sizeof(Deck));
  d->slots = malloc(size*sizeof(char)) ;
  memset(d->slots, 0, d->deck_size);
  d->slot_pointer = 0 ;
  d->deck_size = size ;

  return d ;
}
```

When you do the `memset`, what value does d->deck_size have? It doesn't have any value, which will cause undefined behaviour. You should either move the assignment of `d->deck_size` up to before the `memset` or use `size` like you've done in the call to `malloc`.

Comment: oh my god. you are awesome!! I just moved the assignment of the d->deck_size up and it works perfectly now. thanks so much. you're a lifesaver!!

Comment: @TinaTran If you can, run your executable through something like "valgrind" - it'll find a lot of these kinds of simple, yet hidden mistakes and is also good for finding memory leaks too.